# IPv6 multicast in Contiki or Thingsquare

Tags: networking, ipv6, multicast, contiki, coap

I am working on a project involving some stm32 motes and a border router running Contiki (but I am planning to switch to ThingSquare very soon). The border router is connected via tunslip6 to a computer, and a server is running on the computer. I want the motes to communicate with the server. The problem is that these motes are supposed not to know the address of the server, and to automatically discover it. One solution would be the motes to send a multicast request, and the server to reply to this request. However, my understanding is that the border router is not able to forward a multicast addressed request. Is it true? How can I make this multicast message to propagate just past the border router, staying inside my local LAN?
Are there any Contiki or Thingsquare projects doing this?

Comment: is your question somehow related to programming? if not, it should be moved to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Uhm..ok, actually it isn't.. sorry for that!

Comment: please make yourself familiar with following site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic :)